# Android Lollipop MediaSessionCompat missing setMediaButtonReceiver(PendingIntent)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

For lollipop we are told to replace

`registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()`

with

`setMediaButtonReceiver(PendingIntent)`.

This works in **api21** as MediaSession supports it.

My app goes **api16-21** so i try to use `MediaSessionCompat`.

Sadly it does not support the suggested call change.

I am trying to write friendly code without a bunch of if android version statements,

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed in the support-v4:22.0.0 version. [MediaSessionCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html) now has the `setMediaButtonReceiver(PendingIntent)` call.